# What is this yellow "liquid" on the graphic card?

Tags: integrated-circuit

Currently I've been assigned the task to try to fix a laptop.

The problem was a malfunctioning graphic card.

It has no image what-so-ever.

I've looked all over the circuit and found no burn marks or blown capacitors and resistors, but I've found this yellow "stuff" everywhere:

[image: yellow stuff]

(Excuse my mad Paint skills)

The yellow "stuff" is marked with the red circle.

What is that thing?

Can it be the reason why the graphic card doesn't work?

Comment: Flux residue left over from manufacturing.

Comment: @SomeHardwareGuy I doubt about it. It's badly distributed. The memory also has that yellow thing. memories don't use the same type of soldering.

Comment: Its flux, and yes they do.

Comment: This close reason doesn't make sense. The question is not about repair.

Comment: @CamilStaps It kinda does: I'm asking about what that thing is so I can fix the laptop. And it's obvious that I can't `"demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device being repaired."` since it is a GPU. And, judging by the question, I'm not the one who made the GPU.

Comment: The question what that stuff is, is not specific to repair. This close reason is meant for cases where people want us to help with the technical things of repair. This is just a general wondering, which happens to be in a repair context.

Comment: @CamilStaps You are correct. But even a moderator closed it. I guess that there's nothing much to do with it. Also, I'm not even mad since I got all the information that I needed. But, if you think that I'm not being reasonable, I can post about it on meta.

Comment: No, it's okay. I just came across this question, voted to reopen it, and left a comment for explaining that. Even moderators make mistakes! :)

Comment: @CamilStaps Do you think that adding a disclaimer would help here? The question is a bit old anyway, so, I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: It's not a disclaimer, merely an explanation.

Comment: @CamilStaps I know that. But I could add saying "I don't want to know how to repair, I just want to know what that 'stuff' is." if it helped in anything.

Comment: You can, if you want. But anyway, you have your answer, and this is not your mistake.

Comment: @CamilStaps I doubt it will help in anything. But thank you for explaining why the close reason isn't correct. Most likely no one will see it, but at least is there a valid argument why this shouldn't have been closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would vote for flux too.

I would also note that the most common failure for graphics cards is caused by the heating of the main GPU chip.  The heat causes expansion, and the PCB and the BGP chip both expand by different amounts and at different rates.  This causes the balls of the BGA chip to crack due to the stresses induced.

The fix is to completely reflow the BGA chip using a hot plate, hot air, and flux paste.  A re-balling kit is good too.

Comment: How can I check if it is caused by heating? The client had complained about the card turning off randomly for a few seconds. My first though was heating too, since my card does that when it reaches VERY high temperatures (130-150ºc). Also, a friend of mine had the same problem and it was heat-related.

Comment: +1 to that, sometimes you can make a chip like that work by putting some pressure on it with a thumb.  Sometimes it's cratered it's pads and cracked traces though.  Reflow would be my first try.

Comment: The PS3 suffered from a similar issue.  The fix was to take out the mainboard, wrap it in tin foil, and bake it in the oven.

Comment: @SomeHardwareGuy Sadly, I can't reflow it. I've heard a (bad) suggestion that putting it in the oven for 5-10 minutes MAY work. But I'm not even sure if that is the issue. This laptop was opened a few times by someone other than me.

Comment: A very quick lookup on Google lead me to how to perform a reflow using an oven. Can this be performed using a heatgun at (say) 300ºc?

Comment: For BGA you need to surround it with heat, since the balls are underneath between the chip and the PCB.  To get the heat to the balls with just a heat gun the heat has to pass through the chip itself, which isn't good.  You really need at least a hotplate to heat from underneath while you heat from above with hot air, or an oven so you heat the entire environment.

Comment: Thank you! I've marked it as the accepted answer. I will see what can be done about this. If you want, can you please add, on a section below, what you added on your last comment?